# Can we catch UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, exception

In the following example, I am able to get the resulted printed though was expecting a Runtime exception. Since I have used catch block , does it mean I am able to catch the unchecked exception too? if so than why can't we simple proceed by putting catch block where we suspect a runtime exception to occur.

Below is the code:

```
public class CollectionsSample {

public static void main(String args[]) /*throws UnsupportedOperationException*/{

    Set<String> st = new HashSet<String>();

    st.add("akkhil");
    st.add("gupta");
    Collection<String> coll = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(st);
    try{
    coll.add("changed");
    }catch(Exception e){
        //throw e;
    }

    for(String s : st){
        System.out.println(" " + s);
    }

}
```

This produces output as akkhil gupta though I was expecting it to through runtimeexcption at coll.add("changed");

Comment: What do you think `catch(Exception e)` does?

Comment: What is your understanding about handling exceptions and how do you think it is being done over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it mean I am able to catch the unchecked exception too?

Absolutely, you *can*. However, it does not mean that you *should*.

> why can't we simple proceed by putting catch block where we suspect a runtime exception to occur?

We certainly *can* do that. However, this would be a wrong thing to do, because in a properly designed system runtime exceptions indicate programming errors. These errors need to be fixed in code, rather than caught. For example, if you do not know if a collection is modifiable or not, don't modify it without making a copy.